# Plot previous day high and low in Pinescript renko

Tags: plot, pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to plot the previous day's high in low in the Renko chart. I know how to do it on a normal chart but on Renko unable to plot it.

does anyone have an idea about it??

Answer (score 0):

You can pull normal candle high etc using request.security function like below

```
hi=request.security(ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.regular, adjustment.none),timeframe.period,high)
```

Then you can use hi[1] etc as per need